# Group-Object property behavior

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have below command:

```
foreach ($i in $database) {
    Get-Mailbox -Database $i -ResultSize Unlimited |
        Group-Object -Property Database |
        select Name, Count
}
```

Now what abnormality I am seeing is `Group-Object` is skipping databases from `$database`. It is not querying all the elements from `$database` but randomly skipping some of them specially for which mailbox count is 0.

Want to know why this abnormality. `Group-Object` works fine everywhere. What is that I might be missing.

`$database` when called prints all the database names, no issue here of space and etc.

I used another logic for the same query apart from `Group-Object` and everything is working fine.

Comment: If there is no mailbox I would expect `Get-Mailbox` to not return anything for that database. Hence there'd be nothing for `Group-Object` to group.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are grouping the output of Get-Mailbox, as some of the servers have no mailboxes they output no data to group.